# Flex xml in tree

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

The following xml values is getting from php file

```
<result>
   <list>
      <node>air</node>
      <node>flex</node>
      <node>android</node>
   </list>
</result>
```

i am calling this xml using httpservice

```
 <mx:HTTPService 
        id="project" 
        url="http://localhost/eshpm/AIR/newproject.php"
        method="POST" result="onResult_projectname(event)" resultFormat="e4x">
            <mx:request xmlns="">
                <name>yes</name>
            </mx:request>
</mx:HTTPService>
```

The result is obtained using the function

```
private function onResult_projectname(evt:ResultEvent):void
 {

        xmldata = new XML(evt.result);
        xmlList_user = new XMLListCollection(xmldata.list);             

        tree.dataProvider = xmlList_user.children();            
 }
```

The problem is that i am able to display the values in Tree.......but it is repeating

ie, "air" is comming in tree twice....

plz help.............thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<mx:Tree dataProvider="{project.lastResult.result}" labelField="node"/>`. By invoking `project.send()` databinding works and populates your Tree.